# how is a dictionary sorted?

Tags: python

Ladies and Gents,

I have a question about dictionaries in python.  While playing around I noticed something that *to me* seems strange.

I define a dict like this

stuff={'age':26,'name':'Freddie Mercury', 'ciy':'Vladivostok'}

I then add the word 'first' to stuff like this:

> stuff[1]='first'

When I print it out, it's fine

> stuff
>
> {1: 'first', 'age': 26, 'name': 'Freddie Mercury', 'city': 'Vladivostok'}

Then I add the word second:

> stuff[2]='second'

and that's fine, but when I display the content I get:

> stuff
>
> {1: 'first', 'age': 26, 2: 'second', 'name': 'Freddie Mercury', 'city': 'Vladivostok'}

** notice that 2 is now the third element, and not the second (in order) or the first (if elements are added to the beginning) element

And when I add in the third element 'wtf', now all of a sudden everything is back in order and I'm quite confused as to what's going on.

> stuff[3]='wtf'
>
> stuff
>
> {1: 'first', 2: 'second', 3: 'wtf', 'name': 'Freddie Mercury', 'age': 26, 'city': 'Vladivostok'}

Could someone please explain to me what's going on here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The order you get from a dictionary is undefined.  You should not rely on it.  In this case, it happens to depend on the hash values of the underlying keys, but you shouldn't assume that's always the case.

If order matters to you, use should use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (since Python 2.7):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> stuff=OrderedDict({'age':26,'name':'Freddie Mercury', 'city':'Vladivostok'})
>>> stuff[1]='first'
>>> print stuff
OrderedDict([('city', 'Vladivostok'), ('age', 26), ('name', 'Freddie Mercury'), (1, 'first')])
>>> stuff[2]='second'
>>> print stuff
OrderedDict([('city', 'Vladivostok'), ('age', 26), ('name', 'Freddie Mercury'), (1, 'first'), (2, 'second')])
>>> stuff[3]='wtf'
>>> print stuff
OrderedDict([('city', 'Vladivostok'), ('age', 26), ('name', 'Freddie Mercury'), (1, 'first'), (2, 'second'), (3, 'wtf')])
```

Comment: does that mean that each time i print *stuff* the order may change?

Comment: Yep, exactly. In practice, though, I would only expect the order to change when you add or remove keys - in other words, if you print the dict out twice in a row without adding or removing anything in between, the order will probably be the same. Don't count on that, though.

Comment: Potentially.  In practice, the order should be stable, but can change any time the keys change.  If you really need to rely on a stable ordering, you can either sort the keys as you extract them from the dictionary, or use the `OrderedDict` class.

Comment: okay, so i see how each time you add elements to an OrderedDict i.e.(stuff[1]='first', stuff[2]='second', etc) it adds it to the end, but as far as the original set, i don't see what the order is here. if it's by the the keys, then 'city', 'age', 'name' are not in order, and if it's by the values then 'Vladivostok', 26, 'Freddie Mercury' are not in order either?  or am i missing something here?

Comment: It's related to the order of the hash of the keys, not the keys themselves.  But that's an internal implementation detail, and you can *not* rely on it.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky If you print the dict out twice without adding or removing the order is guaranteed to be the same. See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items "If items(), keys(), values(), iteritems(), iterkeys(), and itervalues() are called with no intervening modifications to the dictionary, the lists will directly correspond."

Answer (score 10):

Dictionaries are unordered data structures, so you should have no expectations

Answer (score 7):

Learn what a hashtable is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

In short, dict has an internal array, and inserts values at slots chosen through a hash function. The nature of this function is that it spreads the entries around evenly.

Answer (score 2):

There *are* some (important) guarantees about order. From the docs (Python 2.7.2) http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items:

> If items(), keys(), values(), iteritems(), iterkeys(), and
>   itervalues() are called with no intervening modifications to the
>   dictionary, the lists will directly correspond. This allows the
>   creation of (value, key) pairs using zip(): pairs = zip(d.values(),
>   d.keys()). The same relationship holds for the iterkeys() and
>   itervalues() methods: pairs = zip(d.itervalues(), d.iterkeys())
>   provides the same value for pairs. Another way to create the same list
>   is pairs = [(v, k) for (k, v) in d.iteritems()].

Answer (score 1):

In a `list`, elements are ordered by their index (position in the list).

A dictionary is, for a all intensive purposes, a bag. Things may move around, but you shouldn't be concerned about that. You access items by their `keys`. You could think of keys as labels, which uniquely identify their `values`.

```
stuff = {} # hey python, please create a bag called stuff.
stuff[1]='first' # hey python, please put the string 'first' in my bag called stuff. 
                 # if I ever need to access 'first' from this bag, I will ask for 1
                 # so please attach the label (key) 1 to the item (value) 'first'
print stuff[1]   # hey python, please find the thing in my bag called stuff
                 # that has a label with 1 attached to it


print stuff[2]   # hey python, please find the thing in my bag called stuff
                 # that has a label called 1 attached to it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
KeyError: 2      # python says "hey programmer, nothing in your bag called stuff has a label with 2 attached to it
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The build in dict gives no guarantee of order of keys after an insertion or deletion.

If you want to keep insertion order (by time of key insertion/update or by key + value insertion/ update) or sorted by key, use the orderddict package http://anthon.home.xs4all.nl/Python/ordereddict/ that I wrote. It is implemented in C (and thus only works for CPython, but almost as fast as the build in `dict`).